# automatically close type parens in C++

Tags: c++, smartparens, balanced-parentheses

Does anybody know of a way or a package that can recognize `<` and `>` when occuring in template contexts and automatically writes a `>` either right after the `<` or after the selected region when typing a `<`? (In other words, that behaves just as normal paren completion.)

I know that `<` and `>`are ambiguous if not evaluated in context and that this might therefore not be possible, that's why I am asking if anybody knows of a solution.

If however not all cases can be covered for technical reasons at least some would be possible, for example whenever `<` is typed right after `template` or when a block is selected that stands after `template`. And maybe some other cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the package `smartparens`. It can be installed from `melpa`.

You can enable pairs of `<>` with:

```
(sp-with-modes '(c-mode c++-mode)
    (sp-local-pair "<" ">"))
```

after `(require 'smartparens-config)`

But be sure to finetune the rule. Have a look at the [pair documentation](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Pair-management) and the [complete documentation](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki).

Comment: thanks, by default the completion for `<` seems to not use any heuristics and acts completely "dumb" and does not recognise when `<` actually is a comparison operator. Do you know if it says how to fix this anywhere in the documentation? When I glanced over it I did not see anything concerning this.

Comment: Have a look here https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Permissions and here https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Wrapping. You can set up filters an triggers. I'm using the package, but I do not yet understand everything. For this rule `local` settings are to be used.  Also have a look at `:when` and `:unless`.

Answer (score 0):

`syntactic-close` as available from Melpa should close any known paired delimiter.

https://github.com/emacs-berlin/syntactic-close